# vue.jsのcustomDirectiveで全角がbindできません

Tags: javascript, vue.js

v-initで２バイト文字を渡すと、以下のエラーになりますが原因がわかりません。
半角英数字及び、objectであれば渡せます。
vue.js自体がbindでの２バイト文字を許容していないのでしょうか？
phpのblade画面からデータを取得する必要があるため、dataに初期定義することはできません。

**v-init="あああ"**
Vue warn]: Property or method "あああ" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

**v-init="１２３４"（全角）**
- invalid expression: v-init="１２３４"

customDirective.vue

```
Vue.directive('init', {
    bind(el, bindings, vnode)
    {
        console.log(el.name, bindings.expression);
        // v-initに渡された値をタグのnameプロパティと同一の名前のv-modelに渡す
        vnode.context[el.name] = bindings.expression ? bindings.expression : '';
    }
});
```

main.js

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        test: ''
    }
});
```

html

```
<main id="main">
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="test" v-init="あああ" v-model="test">
    <form>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

サクッと試してみたところ、ダブルクォーテーションの中身が JavaScript の式として一度評価された後に、評価した式の何らかのメソッドを実行しようとするみたいで、式として成り立つものでなおかつ変数なら定義されているものを入れないとダメっぽいです。

なので半角英数字で定義されていない変数名を入れてやると同じエラーを吐きます。

↓のようにシングルクォーテーションで囲ってやるとかして、`bindings.value` を代入してやれば意図したとおりにいくと思います。

#### html

```
<input type="text" name="test" v-init="'あああ'" v-model="test">
```

#### customDirective.vue

```
vnode.context[el.name] = bindings.value ? bindings.value : '';
```

Comment: 追記：
調べてみたらマルチバイト文字列も変数名として使えるみたいで、式としては一応成り立ってるので、変数として解釈されてしまって、「あああ」という定義されていない変数のメソッドを実行しようとしてエラー吐いてる感じです。

Comment: ありがとうございます、解決いたしました。変数にマルチバイト使えるのですか....